# Is there a way to call SaveChanges() for all actions when system is shutting down?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, mvvm

Is there a way to call SaveChanges for all entities when system is shutting down?

I'm using EF6 and MVVM pattern, and I would like to close and save all actions to the database.

I was trying with `SessionEndReasons.SystemShutdown` but then I need to call all saving methods. Does EF offer some kind of solution to save everything at once?

Thank you

Comment: EF is not designed to be long lived. So I don't understand the necessary.

Comment: Saving process in my app is divided into two. First, employee must run the timer - which save first part of data and when he finish, he stop the timer which will save what he did till timer stop. Sometimes, there is a need to close the computer, and I do not trust to people, so I would like to save everything what he did (in case he 'forgot') before SystemShutdown :) thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may save changes on the applicationExit event:

In your program:

```
Application.ApplicationExit += new EventHandler(this.OnApplicationExit);

private void OnApplicationExit(object sender, EventArgs e) {

    myContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.windows.forms.application.applicationexit(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about a function EF provide, but you can try this:

```
public class foo
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // add the exit handler
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ProcessExit += new EventHandler (OnProcessExit); 
        // your code
    }

    // will be called on exit
    static void OnProcessExit (object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // save your data
        myEntity.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

but it will not be called, if the user kills the prcess